# React Native app crashes with cryptic error when archived: _ZN10TypedArrayIL14TypedArrayKind

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a working React Native app locally. When I archive it to distribute it (either through TestFlight or as IPA. tried both) my app immediately "crashes" (app stays open but React Native is unmounted, stuck in black screen). When I examine logs through Console.app I see the following cryptic error message:

```
8.15.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Warning: NSUncaughtExceptionHandler is '_ZN10TypedArrayIL14TypedArrayKind3EE6updateERN8facebook3jsi7RuntimeERKNSt3__16vectorIhNS6_9allocatorIhEEEE' in '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/28A502B6-6B51-4AE9-84CD-70D88D0DFE41/MyApp.app/MyApp'
```

While I don't have proof, I strongly think it is the cause of the crash as it's a `NSUncaughtExceptionHandler` reported by Crashlytics (which I have in the app as the crash reporter).

When examined closely, the cryptic class/method has some words `TypedArray`, `TypedArrayKind`, `update`, `facebook`, `JSI`, `Runtime`, `vector`, and `allocator`.

I don't have Facebook SDK anywhere in the app so I suspect that "Facebook" is referring to an internal package name in React Native.

I'm stuck. I suspect it's got to do with the JSI runtime but I have no idea how to solve it.

Please note that this problem is occuring only on archived app: there isn't a problem locally when developing.

---

**UPDATE**: I've tried falling back to JSC by using changing `:hermes_enabled => false` in `use_react_native!` (and reinstalling pods after that), yet still the same error.

I've also tried exporting AdHoc and Development export (and installing by AirDropping the IPA) in addition to App Store Connect export: they all yield the same error regardless.

I have app thinning off.

I've tried toggling both "Rebuild from Bitcode" and "Strip Swift symbols" on an off: they all yield the same error regardless.

---

What might be the cause?

Comment: I prefer to move to the last working commit and see the changed code for debugging. Did you get this error for the clean project?

Comment: @VasylNahuliak this is the first time I'm trying to archive the project so unfortunately there's no last working commit.

Comment: Try clean cache https://stackoverflow.com/a/74155983/10617148 or https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-clean-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to latest React Native version (from 0.71.6 to 0.71.8 as of writing), cleaning, and removing Flipper (which I didn't need) the solved the issue.